# Получить элемент списка, сгруппировав его по элементам

Tags: python, psycopg2

уважаемые знатоки. Подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть такой список

```
cur.execute(get_data_from_first_table)

data_frame_from_first_table = cur.fetchall()

data_frame_from_first_table = [ ('1','1','13:40'), ('1','7','13:39'),('1','0','13:38'),('2','10','12:10'),('2','3','12:09'),('3','6','12:08'),('3','0','11:32'),('3','5','11:31'),('3','8','11:30'),('4','2','10:40'),('4','9','10:39'),('4','10','10:38'), ]
```

Можно ли как-то вытащить из него вторую позицию из каждого элемента, при этом сгруппировав их по первому элементу? Немного кривенько объяснил, но должно получиться вот так:

`('1','1','13:40'), ('1','7','13:39'),('1','0','13:38')`  - одинаковый первый элемент, значит в новый список записывается `('1','7','0')`

`('2','10','12:10'),('2','3','12:09')` - одинаковый первый элемент, значит в новый список записывается `('10','3')`

`('3','6','12:08'),('3','0','11:32'),('3','5','11:31'),('3','8','11:30')` - `('6','0','5','8')`

`('4','2','10:40'),('4','9','10:39'),('4','10','10:38')` - `('2','9','10')`

на выходе должно получится следующие: `[('1','7','0'), ('10','3'), ('6','0','5', '8'), ('2','9','10')]`
и так далее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете сами просто собрать в словарь что нужно по ключу и потом развернуть обратно в список списков:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
data_frame_from_first_table = [ ('1','1','13:40'), ('1','7','13:39'),('1','0','13:38'),('2','10','12:10'),('2','3','12:09'),('3','6','12:08'),('3','0','11:32'),('3','5','11:31'),('3','8','11:30'),('4','2','10:40'),('4','9','10:39'),('4','10','10:38'), ]
for data in data_frame_from_first_table:
    d[data[0]].append(data[1])
    
print(list(d.values()))
```

Вывод:

```
[['1', '7', '0'], ['10', '3'], ['6', '0', '5', '8'], ['2', '9', '10']]
```

Хотя, если вам не нужны какие-то данные, выдаваемые запросом и вы их просто выкидываете, так лучше их сразу и не запрашивать.

Comment: Спасибо большое!